# RNG crashing c++ program

Tags: c++, random, overflow, srand

I am currently coding a roguelike, and naturally am using a lot of random number generation.

The problem I'm running up on is that if I "overheat" rand(); my program will crash.

If i'm only generating 20 or so ints per frame, it's fine... but when the amount of random numbers goes into the hundreds, the program crashes. The more I'm producing every frame, the sooner it crashes... which leads me to believe there is some pileup going on.

I've done tests, and at 20 rand(); calls per frame, it will run for 24 hours straight at max speed without crashing. Triple that and it doesn't make it ten minutes.

If I put srand(); in the initialization, i can churn out thousands of random numbers before it locks up - but if I put srand(); within the frame itself, i make it about 2-8 frames. If it matters, I'm using time(null) to seed.

the more frequently i call rand(); the sooner it crashes.

Help?

Comment: Are you sure its crashing within the `rand()` implementation? Have you used a debugger to confirm this behavior? Even if so, unless you can reproduce the problem in a simple case (`int main(void) {while(1) rand(); }`) I would not suspect rand as your problem.

Comment: Show us the minimal failing example

Comment: Are you calling rand from multiple threads?

Comment: Have you been able to to reproduce this under a debugger and see where/why it is crashing?  Or if using a debugger is impractical have you configured it to create a crashdump and then checked that to see where the crash is?  Could you be writing off the end of an array, or having a dangling pointer or the like that could be corrupting memory and so indirectly causing those library routines to crash?

Comment: You've probably done something elsewhere in your code that invokes undefined behavior.  Can you reproduce the crash in a piece of code that does nothing else but calling rand() and srand() repeatedly?

Comment: Nice point on the multi-threadedness possibility.  Take a look at [this article about thread safety and RNGs](http://www.evanjones.ca/random-thread-safe.html) for more about that.

Comment: I am not multithreading - the only real fancy stuff I'm doing with pointers is iterating through a std::set and doing (*it)->run(); to the classes within the set.

Comment: Does it crash inside of a call to rand?

Comment: I am unsure - my debugger isn't playing nice. I just know that after a varying number of turns, the program locks up. I hold down the "next turn" key, and the monsters wander the grid in a random direction each turn. The more monsters I have, the sooner it locks up - and below a certain, small number of monsters it never ever does... which is why I suspect this is some sort of garbage collection problem.

Comment: The only things that use pointers are the turn mechanism, which iterates through a std::set of monster class instances, and various SDL functions that rely on pointers. I free all my SDL surfaces, and so on - so that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments and ideas on how to narrow down the source of the issue:

- It almost certainly is not the `srand()` or `rand()` functions causing the crash/lock up. Chances are that one, or more, combinations of random numbers is getting your engine into a state where something bad happens.
- The first step should be to duplicate the issue such that it always happens at the time/place. Instead of using a `srand(NULL)` try using a constant seed like `srand(12345)`. Depending on what other factors your engine uses (like user input) this may be enough to get it to crash in the same spot each time.
- If using the debugger is having issues (which is suspect, perhaps a buffer overflow is corrupting the stack) use the tried and true method of outputting messages to a text log file. I would suggest outputting all the random numbers generated and perhaps you may see a pattern on when it crashes (i.e, it crashes whenever a "42" is generated). Another option is to start adding a few log message in various functions (start with high level functions like your game update loop). After a crash check the log and begin adding more log messages until you narrow it down to one line/function. This is not as quick as using the debugger can be but is sometimes a better choice, especially if you don't really know where to start looking.
- Once you are able to reliably replicate the crash start removing things until the crash point changes or disappears. This may involve `#ifdef`s, commenting out code, setting application options, or even creating a temporary copy of the project so you can simply delete code, compile, and test. This may be difficult if the project is large/complex.
- More information on the type of "crash" would be helpful. Usually programs don't just crash generically but have a certain exception occur, lock-up, etc.... Exception details can help you narrow down the source of the issue with some effort.

Comment: I found the error and it was something that I had not even concieved of - enemies were ending up surrounded by other enemies, which would cause their movement script to loop infinitely and crash. while if surrounded by walls they'd simply stay put, for some reason being surrounded by other entities didn't trigger the "stand still" default case, so the "check adjacent squares for collision loop would go on forever" - hence the always-different length of time before the crash. It was a specific, unique, picky case - but inevitable, and more likely with more enemies.

Answer (score 1):

> The function rand() is not reentrant or thread-safe, since it uses hidden state that is modified on each call.  This might just be the seed value to
>      be used by the next call, or it might be something more elaborate.  In order to get reproducible behavior in a threaded application, this state must
>      be made explicit.  The function rand_r() is supplied with a pointer to an unsigned int, to be used as state.  This is a very small amount of  state,
>      so this function will be a weak pseudo-random generator.  Try drand48_r(3) instead.

Comment: I had the same idea, but apparently this is a single threaded program.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it under a debugger

```
$ gdb myprog
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
(gdb) record
```

e.g.

```
(gdb) break abort
(gdb) break exit
```

since it is c++:

```
(gdb) catch throw
(gdb) catch exception
```

and finally
    (gdb) continue

When it stops, reverse-continue until you find the culprit

---

Option 2:

```
valgrind --tool=massif --massif-out-file="massif.out.%p" myprog
ms_print massif.out.*
```

to examine heap profiling. Not unlikely you have a memory leak

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the high number of calls to rand are coming up with a number in a relatively small range which your code cannot handle. Try replacing your calls to rand with a function that just increments a number and returns it, and see if it eventually fails.

Answer (score 0):

1. You probable shouldn't be using rand(). There are far better PRNGs out there. Have a look at Boost.Random.
2. You should only srand() once, not every frame.
3. Find out where your code crashes. Using a debugger that's fairly easy, just start the program with the debugger attached and wait until it crashes.
4. After you have found out where it crashes, find out why it crashes.
5. After you have found out why, fix it. It probably doesn't have anything to do with rand().